# How to solve a complex equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, functions

I am trying to solve a complex equation for 'z' in terms of 'f'. At the moment my Mathematica is stuck running... 
Just wondering if anyone has any ideas, I know 0 < z < 40 if that helps.

[image]

```
w1 = 0.3575
w2 = 0.0174
C1 = (5536113736801657*f)/72057594037927936
C2 = -(4347531554729451*f)/75557863725914323419136
C3 = -(3725665976080763*f)/4503599627370496
C4 = (6759318253327467*f)/9007199254740992
d = -w1*C1*Exp[-w1*z] + w1*C2*Exp[w1*z] - w2*C3*Exp[-w2*z] + w2*C4*Exp[w2*z]
dddz = D[d, z]
dd2dz2 = D[dddz, z]
Solve[dd2dz2 == 0, z]
```

Comment: I just used the plot function and found z is max at z = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's replace the remaining floating point values with rational numbers

```
w1 = 3575/10000
w2 = 174/10000
```

, simplify it

```
expr = Simplify[dd2dz2, z > 0 && f \[Element] Reals]
```

, which shows that `f` can be factored out completely, which means `f==0` is a solution for every `z`. We are probably more interested in the non trivial solutions, so let's divide out `f` to focus on the other solutions

```
expr2 = Simplify[dd2dz2/f // PowerExpand, z > 0 && f \[Element] Reals]
```

which is a sum of weighted exponentials in `z` with different rate coefficients. `Reduce` is able to give us the two remaining solutions in the form of `Root` objects:

```
sol = Reduce[expr2 == 0 && z > 0, z]
sol//N
```

[image: reduce output]

using `N` gives us a good numerical approximation. Looking at the `InputForm` shows that Mathematica keeps perfect analytical solutions in terms of roots of polynomials:

```
sol//InputForm
```

[image: input form]

Answer (score 0):

```
ContourPlot[dd2dz2 == 0, {z, 0, 40}, {f, -1 , 1},MaxRecursion-> 4,FrameLabel -> {z, f}]
```

[image]

shows the solution `{z,f}`